# How to Send control+option from Windows client to Mac VNC Screen Sharing?

Tags: mac, vnc, realvnc

I need to be able to send control+option+arrows from Windows client to Mac with vnc screen sharing enabled.

However, RealVNC sends command key when I press alt key.

According to the page below, it's supposed to send option if I press right alt, but it still sends command.

https://archive.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/4.5/mac/mac_keyboard_mapping.html

I also tried scroll lock, and then it sends command key for both windows and alt.

I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: What's ctrl/opt/arrow supposed to do on the Mac? It's not a shortcut I know.

Comment: It's accessibility shortcuts for navigating MacOS with VoiceOver.

Comment: Oh, I see what they're doing & the change from 4.4 to 4.5.. I'm afraid I've no idea how to work around that, sorry. Maybe going back to 4.4 or even seeing what the newer version does...